# Two system services need write access to the same directory - How to correctly set users/groups etc to permit access securely?

Tags: permissions, groups, acl

I am trying to run two system services, each of which has its own user, and creates files owned by that user, in a directory under /var/lib - The problem is that I need both services to write their files into the same directory, and a file written by one to be readable by the other.

I was able to workaround the problem with `chmod 0777` on the directory and all it's parents, but that does not feel like a wise long term solution. Is there a better approach to resolve the permissions? Perhaps by adding both users to the same group?

I am running 20.04 LTS Focal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options.

Yes, you can add both users to the same group and set write access to this group:

```
sudo groupadd somegroup
sudo adduser user1 somegroup
sudo adduser user2 somegroup
sudo chgrp somegroup /var/lib/somedir
sudo chmod g+rwx /var/lib/somedir
```

You can also set the directory to be owned by `user1` and belonging to group to which `user2` belongs, and then set write access for both owner and group:

```
# assume group2 is a group to which user2 belongs
sudo chown user1:group2 /var/lib/somedir
sudo chmod ug+rwx /var/lib/somedir
```

Finally, you can use ACLs. First you have to install the commands to manipulate ACLs:

```
sudo apt install acl
```

Then you can eg. make the directory owned by `user1` and add write access for `user2`:

```
sudo chown user1 /var/lib/somedir
sudo chmod u+rwx /var/lib/somedir
sudo setfacl -m u:user2:rwx /var/lib/somedir
```

Or you can explicitly add access for `user1` and `user2` regardless of who is the owner of the directory:

```
sudo setfacl -m u:user1:rwx /var/lib/somedir
sudo setfacl -m u:user2:rwx /var/lib/somedir
```

BTW. You don't need write access on the parent directories (0777), what you need is the `x` access to each parent directory only.